# Which permissions shall I set in azure active directory to get the details of all items in an onedrive business account?

Tags: azure-active-directory, onedrive, office365api

I have added details of my native application in azure active directory and added permission to "sign and read user profile" for Windows Azure Active Directory application and permission to "Read and Write user files" for Office 365 Sharepoint online application.After adding these permissions, I am able authenticate the user and retrieve access token for the user's one drive business account.But when I call webservice to retrieve default drive details, it gives me "401 unauthorized error".And when I try to call webservice to retrieve children of default drive then I get "403 Forbidden" error.So, I added another permission to "Read managed metadata" for the Office 365 Sharepoint online application in azure.But then I get following error while trying to login the user using oAuth.[image]

Is it due to lack of priveleges to the user's onedrive business account or some problem in permission that I set in azure active directory?

Comment: try to set "User assignment required to access app" to false in the app config page in azure ad

Comment: I couldn't find such setting, if you are referring to "USERS MAY GIVE APPLICATIONS PERMISSION TO ACCESS THEIR DATA" setting in active directory configuration.Then it is set to "Yes".Shall I set it to no?